How do I play the scratchy guitar part of evh in the song BEAT IT
in the Michael Jackson song BEAT IT, the parts where EVH played, there is this part where it sound like a muted funky scratchy electric guitar part before the solo. How do I do that. I can't get the sound. Something to do with the amp setting or the way I mute ? Set gain higher tone higher or what ?

That’s not Eddie Van Halen in that part, I think it’s Steve Lukather. The only EVH stuff that made it to the final mix is the solo.

Ok so my mistake. Indeed it is Steve. So how to do that part

Then please [edit] your post and remove Eddie Van Halen references in the title/body. Also avoid such terms in future posts: "EVH" is not a common abbreviation, the fact that people very familiar with the song and its background may understand it is irrelevant. Also, MP&T is not a tutorial website: we don't generally provide "guides" on how to get a specific sound based on "how to do xyz" posts: did you actually try to get it? What did you get? Providing recordings of your attempts would be much more helpful to properly guide you in understanding why you didn't get it and help you with it.

@musicamante - since EVH is not a common abbreviation, I Googled it, and guess what - Eddie came up! So, no problem using those (rare) initials! SL would have been more problematic, though.

@Tim I agree, and anybody could Goggle it like with any other abbreviation, including more common ones. Yet, Google can give very different results depending on the user search history; it may not be this case, but I don't really see the point of abbreviating a person's name.

@musicamante- my point was more that people reading this site would be conversant with how EVH is often known - EVH.

@Tim I get your point. Still, even though I'm a common user of this site and familiar with many musical genres (and I do know about Van Halen), I didn't get the EVH reference. We're not talking about a relatively common abbreviation or net slang within a phrase, nor (more importantly) a technical musical abbreviation that almost anybody here would know (eg: "pp" or "dc") because it's part of general music practice and theory, but a fundamental aspect of the question for which even somebody not well versed in specific guitar techniques or amplification may provide help.

@Tim And that doesn't even consider search query aspects; let's assume that Van Halen was the actual performer (even though he wasn't, as per Todd's note) and nobody ever wrote the full name in comments or in a possible answer: a user may have searched a related query using "[Eddie ]Van Halen" instead of "EVH" for a similar question, and this post could have been possibly shown with a low score (possibly, many pages after the first results). Such usage of uncommon abbreviations isn't helpful to anybody; the fact that we (as frequent users) could eventually look them up is irrelevant.
